# jsPDF v2.1.1 - doc.html is not a function - 10.2020

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

today is October 31, 2020 and i've already read the documentation, but to be honest i don't understood a hundred porcent, otherwise i should have my answer.
I saw a comment from that says:  @HackbrettXXX commented 26 days ago
**fromHTML is deprecated. Use html instead.**

doc:https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

I tried to use **doc.html($('#pdfprintcontentarea').html(), 15, 15, {**
or only **html($('#pdfprintcontentarea').html(), 15, 15, {**
but no success until yet.

**The Library got a new update and i don't know how can i to fix this point.**

The same example running:
https://codepen.io/AshikNesin/pen/KzgeYX

This is the very simple Script that i'm using and there is example on codede running.

**printpagepdfsimple.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    console.log(doc)
    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function(element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    $('#cmd').click(function() {
        doc.fromHTML($('#pdfprintcontentarea').html(), 15, 15, {
            'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });
        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
    });
   
});
```

**Error Message in the console:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
    at f.renderParagraph (jspdf.153.min.js?ver=1.0.0:202)
    at f.setBlockBoundary (jspdf.153.min.js?ver=1.0.0:202)
    at k (jspdf.153.min.js?ver=1.0.0:202)
    at k (jspdf.153.min.js?ver=1.0.0:202)
    at k (jspdf.153.min.js?ver=1.0.0:202)
    at k (jspdf.153.min.js?ver=1.0.0:202)
    at k (jspdf.153.min.js?ver=1.0.0:202)
    at k (jspdf.153.min.js?ver=1.0.0:202)
    at jspdf.153.min.js?ver=1.0.0:202
    at l (jspdf.153.min.js?ver=1.0.0:202)
f.renderParagraph   @   jspdf.153.min.js?ver=1.0.0:202
f.setBlockBoundary  @   jspdf.153.min.js?ver=1.0.0:202
k   @   jspdf.153.min.js?ver=1.0.0:202
k   @   jspdf.153.min.js?ver=1.0.0:202
k   @   jspdf.153.min.js?ver=1.0.0:202
k   @   jspdf.153.min.js?ver=1.0.0:202
k   @   jspdf.153.min.js?ver=1.0.0:202
k   @   jspdf.153.min.js?ver=1.0.0:202
(anonymous) @   jspdf.153.min.js?ver=1.0.0:202
l   @   jspdf.153.min.js?ver=1.0.0:202
d   @   jspdf.153.min.js?ver=1.0.0:202
m   @   jspdf.153.min.js?ver=1.0.0:202
t.fromHTML  @   jspdf.153.min.js?ver=1.0.0:202
(anonymous) @   printpagepdfsimple.js?ver=1.0.0:10
dispatch    @   jquery-2.1.3.min.js?ver=1.0.0:3
r.handle    @   jquery-2.1.3.min.js?ver=1.0.0:3
```

I'm using the library inside the wordpress, but this should work everywhere.
**The links:**

**1°**

```
function p5_jQuery_Lib(){
    
        wp_enqueue_script('jQueryLib', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );

        wp_enqueue_script('jQueryLibalt', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
    }   

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'p5_jQuery_Lib' );
```

**2°**

```
function p5_js_153(){

        wp_enqueue_script('printpdf153', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jspdf.153.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );        
    }                                                                                  
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'p5_js_153' );
```

What am i doing wrong please?

Gratitude for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The `fromHTML` function seems to been deprecated yes but that also means it is no longer available. So instead of still tring to use `fromHTML` like this,

```
doc.fromHTML($('#pdfprintcontentarea').html(), 15, 15, {
  'width': 170,
  'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});
```

you could try something along the lines of,

```
doc.html($('#pdfprintcontentarea'), {
  x: 15,
  y: 15,
});
```

I hope that might help?

Comment: Hi....Thank you so much for your help, but i had a lot of headaches with this library, so i decided to change for the mPDF Library. Another points is,  the jsPDF v2.1.1 Library does not deliver many functions as you wish. In special to use CSS with the generated PDF file.